# android generate firebase token and send to node js server

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, notifications, google-cloud-firestore

I been looking for a solution as to how send a firebase registration token to a server but I have not been able to find one.

Basically I am developing an app which allows sending device to device notifications using a Node js service as server and firestore for the notifications. So far I have device to device notifications working but the registration tokens used were typed in into the Node js server.

I am wondering how can I send a newly generated token to the node js server so the newly installed app can receive and send push notifications? i

Also what would i have to implement in the app and/or service ?

Below is a snippet from my node JS server  which is currently working but only the tokens which are inside the array.

```
'use-strict'

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp();
//admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

//Existing tokens
var registrationTokens = [ ... ]

exports.sendNotificationfunctions.firestore.document('Phones/{phone_id}/Notifications/{notifications_ 
 id}').onWrite((change, context) => {

const phone_id = context.params.phone_id;
const notifications_id = context.params.notifications_id;

return admin.firestore().collection("Phones").doc(phone_id).collection("Notifications").doc(notifications_id).get().then( queryResult => {

     // Retrieve data

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload, options).then(function(response){
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    })


}); 

});
```

Comment: Do you need to send the FCM tokens from android client to server?

Comment: Your server should have the functionality to receive and register Firebase tokens from your clients. Whenever a client get's a new token, it should send this to your server. However, your clients will also need some unique identifier, so that your server can match the clients Firebase token, even if it does change over time.